# Pointcut is not well-formed

Tags: spring-aop

I am learning spring AOP. While trying an example I am getting the "Pointcut is not well-formed" exception. Below is the exception in detail:

Code:
    package org.aspectDemo.aspect.com;

```
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class LogginAspect {
    @Before("allGetters()")
    public void LoggingAdvice(){
        System.out.println("Advice run. Get method called");
    }
    @Pointcut("execution(* * org.aspectDemo.model.com.Circle.*())")
    public void allGetters(){}

}
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting '(' at character position 14
execution(* * org.aspectDemo.model.com.Circle.*())
            ^^^

    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.resolvePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:316)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.InternalUseOnlyPointcutParser.resolvePointcutExpression(InternalUseOnlyPointcutParser.java:36)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.Java15ReflectionBasedReferenceTypeDelegate.getDeclaredPointcuts(Java15ReflectionBasedReferenceTypeDelegate.java:309)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.getDeclaredPointcuts(ReferenceType.java:884)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType$PointcutGetter.get(ResolvedType.java:243)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType$PointcutGetter.get(ResolvedType.java:241)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.Iterators$4$1.hasNext(Iterators.java:213)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.Iterators$4.hasNext(Iterators.java:230)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType.findPointcut(ResolvedType.java:743)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.ReferencePointcut.resolveBindings(ReferencePointcut.java:148)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.Pointcut.resolve(Pointcut.java:189)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.resolvePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:313)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:294)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:212)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:199)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.checkReadyToMatch(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:188)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getClassFilter(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:168)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:208)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:262)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:294)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:88)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:372)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:421)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1558)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-examples) you seem to have one asterisk too much. Also, "any arguments" is encoded as `(..)` Your expression should be

```
execution(* org.aspectDemo.model.com.Circle.*(..))
```